# WP theme check plugin errors not showing location

Tags: wordpress, debugging, plugins, error-handling, wordpress-theming

I have converted a theme HTML to WP. Now I am checking the theme with WP Check plugin. It's showing this two warning, but not showing the exact location. How can I find where is missing, the text domain name?

```
WARNING: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function __, with the arguments ''

WARNING: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function __, with the arguments ''
```